# How to run Play in production mode?

Tags: playframework

How can I run Play! in production mode, so that it doesn't print source code to the browser window in case of an exception?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several methods, the easiest way is to run `play start` instead of `play run`.

You can find more information on the documentation: [Starting your application in production mode](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/latest/Production)

Comment: I usually do target/start as described at the page behind your docs link, but in case of an exception it still bares my source code :-/

Comment: Weird... `play stage` (before `target/start`) doesn't package source files... What play version do you use, and what command do you launch exactly?

Comment: I do `play clean compile stage` and afterwards launch the result by `/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --exec \`pwd\`/target/start --background -- -Dhttp.port=9090`

Comment: My play version is 2.0.4 (current version).

Comment: For me it's the correct process. You should check with play2.1RC2, and if it's not working, open a ticket.

Comment: Hey sorry for my confusion. The error occured at a colleague's machine, but in development mode. I was sure it also occured on our production server. But in fact this was not the case. Many thanks anyway for your qualified reply, Julien! I was just too upset and couldn't think clearly any more. Beforehand we had great troubles concerning the network configuration due to restrictions introduced by our Internet provider.

Answer (score 17):

While being in the sbt console, [you can also run your app in Prod mode](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Running-a-test-instance) with

```
[my-first-app] $ testProd
```

Also useful is to use this command to prevent sbt exiting when pressing `CTRL`+`D`

```
[my-first-app] $ testProd --no-exit-sbt
```

In **Play 2.6**, [`testProd` was renamed to `runProd`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#Running-a-test-instance):

```
[my-first-app] $ runProd
```

Comment: In Play 2.6.x, the task has been renamed to `runProd`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SBT you can run it in production mode with the following command

```
$ sbt runProd
```